# How do I write IPv4 slash notation in IPV6

Tags: postgresql, tcpip

I have the following IPv4 address and mash in my Postgres `hba.conf` file:

```
192.168.0.0/24
```

Which works great when connecting my other Mac perfectly as long as I connect to the PostgreSQL database server directly using it's IPv4 address. But how do I convert it to IPv6?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Super User or Unix/Linux.

Comment: You might find some information here in the following document titled: [Subnet masks (IPv4) and prefixes (IPv6)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/STCMML8/com.ibm.storage.ts3500.doc/opg_3584_IPv4_IPv6_prefix_subnet_mask.html) (IBM Documentation)

Answer (score 1):

The `/24` in IPv4 is for small network. You can translate it in `/96` for IPv6.

Here's the quote from [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) :

> An IPv6 address range might look like ::1/128 for a single host (in
>   this case the IPv6 loopback address) or fe80::7a31:c1ff:0000:0000/96
>   for a small network.